# Correct misspelled words with Python

Tags: python, string, spell-checking

I need to clean the misspelling words in a query like "eat an appple", "eat an bannnna". I have tried the autocorrect function but it only works for single words.

```
from autocorrect import spell
spell("appple")
```

it returns the correct word "apple". However, for the whole sentence, it does not work.

I wonder if there is any easier way to automatically correct the misspelling words in a sentence without writing a loop.

Comment: If you want to use the `autocorrect` package, you'll need to do some kind of iteration over the words in the sentence.

Comment: What have you tried and what problems have you encountered?

Answer (score 3):

"Without a loop"

```
>>> ' '.join(map(spell, 'i like appples'.split()))
'i like apples'
```

Unfortunately, you still need some mechanism of autocorrecting each word separately, for which a loop, or "looping" construct (such as `map`) cannot be avoided.